# Angular 5 datalist need to show description on click need to send value

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, angular5, datalist, html-datalist

I am using datalist in angular 5 for one functionality like drop down.

Initially I am loading description and value in datalist. But when I select the description from datalist it shows value for that description in text box. Instead of I want to show the description in text box when clicking on button I need to send the value for that description.

My code

```
<Input type="text" list="data" id="test">
<datalist id="data">
<option *ngFor="let data of test" [value]="data.id">{{data.description}}</option>
</datalist>
```

Currently if I am selecting option in datalist it shows value of id in textbox. Instead of I need to show description. Then on click I have to send value of id in form like selectbox.

Thanks in advance.